# how to point www.example.com/blog to another IP using dns

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm a dns newbie .

my dns entry www.example.com points to one IP address . we have another blog hosted on blog.example.com which is hosted on another IP.
Is there any way using DNS to point requests www.example.com/blog to the blog IP address ?
I'm hosting my dns on godaddy ..

Answer (score 3):

You can't achieve this using DNS - you would have to instruct the webserver hosting www.example.com to issue an HTTP redirect from www.x.com/blog to blog.example.com.

DNS only resolves a domain name (www.example.com) to an IP. The '/blog' bit is an instruction to the webserver from the web browser only comes into play once the DNS lookup has already completed.